# Flash Media Server with Apache already installed

Tags: apache-2.2, flash, flash-media-server

i have apache already installed and I want to know the right way to install FMS on windows and be able to run the FMS. I have installed FMS but I cannot start it! When I go to windows>programs>adobe>FMS>start fms it does not start the service (I dont see the icon on the bottom right of my screen next to the apache server icon)

how can I connect to admin console. I have port 1935 open but still when I type mysite.com:1935 it does not show anything.

any suggestions is appreciated

Comment: An icon in the system tray is not an indicator of whether a service is running, except in the rare cases where the application provides that.  What does `services.msc` say?

Comment: thank you ... I checked services.msc and it shows it running "started"

Answer (score 0):

The administration console are local html and swf files, found here; C:\Program Files\Adobe\Flash Media Server 4.5\tools\fms_adminConsole.htm

The admin console connect over port 1111 by default, not 1935.